# how to identify message was successfully post using Graph API in ios?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook-graph-api, ios5

I have use *`Facebook Graph API`* for post feed on Facebook  wall.

I have use following code for this

```
 [[delegate facebook] dialog:@"feed"
                  andParams:dictionary
                andDelegate:self];
```

Now, when we tap on post button, Open the *`Facebook Dialog`* with share and cancel button.

now, I tap on *`cancel`* or *`share`* button, it's going to following delegate method of *`FBDialogDelegate`*.

```
-(void)dialogDidComplete:(FBDialog *)dialog {

NSLog(@"Dialog Did Complete"); 

}
```

So, how to identify, my message was successfully share or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the dialogCompleteWithUrl callback, parse the URL returned. If you get a post_id as one of the query parameters, it was successfully posted.

See also: [Feed dialog using ios sdk.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/feed-dialog-using-ios-sdk/)